# Why is my Perl script hanging when executed via SSH?

Tags: perl, ssh, fork, nagios

I've developed a small Nagios monitoring scripts which basically runs a tcpdump on a given interface and port, and looks for a particular string in the first 10 captured packets. I'm monitoring a system which may hang and flood my server with a particular message.

I'm not a professional Perl programmer, but I believe I've treated all expections I could.

Running this script locally ends just fine, and returns the console to me. However, when I try to run it via my Nagios server, via ssh (ssh user@host -i private_key '/path/script.pl'), the script is executed sucessfully, I get the exit message, however, ssh does not exit. I have to either Ctrl+C or hit a few returns to get bash back to me. Running it with check_by_ssh yelds me a plugin timeout error, for obvious reasons.

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the fork() I'm using, but I don't know what is wrong with it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my $RC_OK = 0;
my $RC_WARNING = 1;
my $RC_CRITICAL = 2;
my $RC_UNKNOWN = 3;

my $GREP_RC = undef;

my $PORT = undef;
my $INT = undef;
my $STRING = undef;

my $PID = undef;

# Handler principal de alarme de timeout
$SIG{ALRM} = sub {
    print "UNKNOWN: Main script timed out!\n";
    exit $RC_UNKNOWN;
};

# Inicio contagem global
alarm(8);

# Coleta parametros
GetOptions ("port=s" => \$PORT,
            "interface=s" => \$INT,
            "string=s" => \$STRING);

# Sanity check de parametros
if((not defined $PORT) || (not defined $STRING)) {
    print "Usage: ./check_stratus.pl -p=PORT -i=INTERFACE -s=STRING\n";
    exit $RC_UNKNOWN;
}

# Capturando pelo tcpdump
defined($PID = fork()) or die "Problema ao criar o fork: $!\n";
if ($PID == 0) {

    # Handler secundario de alarme de timeout
    $SIG{ALRM} = sub {
        exit 1;
    };

    # Captura no maximo por 5 segundos, ou 10 pacotes
    alarm(5);

    `sudo /usr/sbin/tcpdump -nX -s 2048 -c 10 -i $INT port $PORT > /tmp/capture.txt 2>&1`;

    # Checando se o tcpdump rodou com sucesso
    if ($? != 0) {
        print "Erro ao executar \"/usr/sbin/tcpdump -nX -s 2048 -c 1 -i $INT port $PORT > /tmp/capture.txt\", verifique o arquivo de saida para mais detalhes.\n";
        exit $RC_UNKNOWN;
    }
    exit $RC_OK;
}

# Espera o filho encerar...
waitpid($PID, 0);

# Verificando se o arquivo capturado esta ok
`/bin/ls /tmp/capture.txt`;

if ($? != 0) {
    print "Erro ao encontrar o arquivo /tmp/capture.txt\n";
    exit $RC_UNKNOWN;
}

# Executando grep da string em cima da captura
`/bin/grep $STRING /tmp/capture.txt`;

# Verificando resultado do grep
if ($? == 0) {
    print "Foi encontrada a string \"$STRING\" na captura do tcpdump escutando na interface $INT e na porta $PORT!\n";
    exit $RC_CRITICAL;
}

if ($? == 256) {
    print "Nao foi encontrada a string \"$STRING\" na captura do tcpdump escutando na interface $INT e na porta $PORT.\n";
    exit $RC_OK;
} else {
    print "Erro desconhecido! Codigo do grep foi $?\n";
    exit $RC_UNKNOWN;
}
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: any idea why you need fork here ? if for alarm, try command `timeout 5 /usr/sbin/tcpdump....`

Comment: tshark have  own timeout `tshark -a 'duration: 1'`

Comment: btw, if you need to check the file presence use `if (!-f "/tmp/capture.txt") {..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look here:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my $PID;
defined($PID = fork()) or die "no fork works";
if ($PID == 0) {

    # Handler secundario de alarme de timeout
    $SIG{ALRM} = sub {
        exit 1;
    };

    # Captura no maximo por 5 segundos, ou 10 pacotes
    alarm(1);
    `sleep 100`;
}
waitpid($PID, 0);
```

---

```
/tmp$ ps xawww |grep sleep
 1705 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep sleep
host:/tmp$ time /tmp/test.pl

real    0m1.008s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.004s
host:/tmp$ ps xawww |grep sleep
 1708 pts/2    S      0:00 sleep 100
 1710 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep sleep
```

The problem appears because your system fork a new process and that process not get signal from parent process.

Solution is just use `exec()` instead of ``` `` ``` or `system()` as `exec()` does not fork new process:

```
    alarm(1);
    exec("sleep 100");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! The exec command did the trick, but still, timing out it was a much more elegant way to solve my problem, and I did not even have to resort to forking my script.